# show GPS location with WP7 on a panel?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I know that you can show current GPS moving location on map with WP7 but i have an application that works offline, i must show user's location according to some other already saved locations in application, how can i show user location?

Comment: You can find answer from this Link...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890185/show-gps-location-with-wp7-on-a-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the coordinates and want to display on bing maps im afraid its not possible.. bing map doesn't work offline. You need some way to cache the map tiles but not on bing maps.. the terms of bing maps doesn't allow you to save their map images. you can look at the following links see if they do any help.

[Map Tile Caching for Offline Viewing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068891/map-tile-caching-for-offline-viewing)

[Windows Phone 7 Map Control with custom layer in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386391/windows-phone-7-map-control-with-custom-layer-in-offline-mode)

if not you can try caching the location as an image tagged to the location..

Comment: Rejinderi,I know how to display GPS locations on map witch is online, but it's not my aim.i want to representing a saved area(boundary points of an area) with a graphic points just on a black screen, converting lat/long to x/y and draw them

Comment: just i want to know is it possible or not, having some thing like that with offline application

Comment: its possible.. as long as you can get coordinates from the satellite without failing